# Remove header and footer of the page when export node to pdf using print module

Tags: nodes, files

When I use the [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module for export node to the pdf file are facing a problem that I could not handle that it automatically generates header and footer for my page pdf. I want to remove the header and footer of the page. Can someone guide me how to deal with it. Thank you very much.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to

**Home » Administration » Configuration » User interface » Printer, email and PDF versions**

then in **SETTINGS** page, check option **none** in **FOOTER OPTIONS** tab.

[image]

Comment: I have tried to do so but failed. Thank you :(

Comment: Did you try with custom tpl or css..??  **By editing the default print.css or specifying your own CSS file and/or the print.tpl.php files, it is possible to change the look of the output page to suit your taste. For a more fine-grained customization, it is possible to use a template file named:

Drupal 6: print[_html|_mail|_pdf][.node-node-type].tpl.php
located in either the current theme or the module directory.
Drupal 7: print[--html|--mail|--pdf][--node--node-type].tpl.php
located in the current theme directory.**

Comment: i have custom css and tpl but were unsuccessful. Hihi